# Join two =if - excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have this two if functions:

```
=IF(C5<15;15-C5;0)
=IF(C5>15;C5-15;0)
```

Is it possible to join them into the same cell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could nest the if statements:

```
If(C5<15;15-C5;If(C5>15;C5-15;0))
```

Since both have `0` as the "Else" parameter (when the condition is false) you could add them together:

```
 =IF(C5<15;15-C5;0) + IF(C5>15;C5-15;0)
```

Since it's just arithmetic you could get rid of the ifs:

```
 =((C5<15)*(15-C5)) + ((C5>15)*(C5-15))
```

Also... this whole mess could be simplified down to just:

```
 =ABS(C5-15)
```

Comment: you have a typo there that I can't correct because it is just one character and I have to edit 6 :-P You wrote `5` instead of `15` in the nested formula

Comment: Awesomesauce. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
If(C5<15;15-C5;If(C5>15;C5-15;0))
```